# Enable WooCommerce My account Payment Methods allowing Customer To Add a Payment Method

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, account, payment-method

I am trying to allow the customer to add a payment method just like he or she can edit their address and everything else.

So, I added this code to the `My account => Payment Methods`. But when clicked, it just says that "New payment methods can only be added on checkout" or something like that.

**So, any solution to this?**

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_account_payment_methods', 'add_payment_method_from_my_account' );
function add_payment_method_from_my_account() { ?>

    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'add-payment-method' ) ); ?>">
    <?php esc_html_e( 'Add payment method', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
    
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something completely different, as the desired payment gateways, need to **support** ["add_payment_method" feature](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.1/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-account-functions.php#L119) *(or "tokenization" feature)*.

So we don't need your code (and all other related code that you have added).

But, we can enable "add_payment_method" feature for some defined payment gateways.

Remove/disable all your related code and use instead the following hooked function:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateway_supports', 'filter_payment_gateway_supports', 10, 3 );
function filter_payment_gateway_supports( $supports, $feature, $payment_gateway ) {
    // Here in the array, set the allowed payment method IDs (slugs)
    $allowed_payment_method_ids = array('bacs', 'cheque', 'cod');

    if ( in_array($payment_gateway->id, $allowed_payment_method_ids ) && $feature === 'add_payment_method' ) {
        $supports = true;
    }
    return $supports;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

This time "Payment methods" menu item appears in My account menu items and when going to "Payment methods" section, there is a **functional** "Add payment method" button.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, there is a list of available gateways according to the array provided, but adding a payment method does not work (debit card, credit card etc). It says, "Could not add payment method to your account."

Perhaps I was unclear in my question, but I need the customer to be able to add a "method" as in debit or credit card before having placed their first order.

Comment: In that case you may need to ask a new question with all required details (with the linked payment plugin used), the related code and explanations. This way we will be able to have a testable example for this issue.

Comment: I don't have one except for Stripe, which I added to the array. Should I ask a new question?

Comment: If stripe plugin doesn't handle tokenization at the shop level, there will not be any way to get that working. Also, you should avoid playing with this, as this can be something risky and illegal. Saving credit card customer  sensible data locally in the shop, is not a good idea, as WooCommerce / WordPress can be easily hacked.